# Saving many-to-many data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am attempting to create a simple blog using laravel.

Unfortunately, I got lost attempting to attach a tag to a new post through the eloquent many-to-many relationships.

Any help would be appreciated figuring this out:

Models:

```
//post.php
public function blogTags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('BlogTag', 'blogTag_post', 'post_id', 'blogTag_id');
}

//BlogTag.php
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Post', 'blogTag_post', 'blogTag_id', 'post_id');
}
```

Tag html from view (`$categories` passed in from the get method):

```
<h3> Tags </h3>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="tag">
        @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

My store function in my controller

```
$post = new Post();
$post->post_title  = Input::get('post_title');
$post->month = Input::get('month');
$post->date = Input::get('date');
$post->post_body    = Input::get('post_body');
$post->picture_path = $destinationPath ."/". $filename;
$post->post_author = $author;
$post->save();

foreach (Input::get('tag') as $tagId) {
    // look up the existing Tag by ID
    $tag = BlogTag::find($tagId);

    // save the Tag on the Post
    $post->blogTags()->save($tag);
}
```

I think I have talked myself in circles.

Specifically, my questions are:

- How do I send the multiple values from the select input to my Controller method?
- Is `$post->blogTags()->save($tag);` the correct way to attach data to a pivot table using eloquent?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the select input in the view.

so I changed this:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="tag">
                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

to

```
{{Form::select('tag[]', $categories, null, array('multiple' => true));}}
```

The many-to-many relationship data is now being saved in the db.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you were having in your first attempt wasn't that you weren't using the Laravel Form helper method, it was that you weren't passing the multiple data as an array, and that the select element was missing a name attribute. By including the name you would have gotten a value passed through, but only ever one. Using the array notation (foo[]) is what allows for the multiple values.

The following should work as well if you want to do it in html:

```
<select multiple name="tag[]" class="form-control" id="tag">
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

On a sidenote, I would also do a conditional check if $tag exists before you try to save it to a post.